# Update UIButton directly or SetNeedsDisplay

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a custom UITableViewCell class that contains a UIButton for favoriting the cell. When the user taps the button it toggles the "favorite" state. Is the following code the correct approach to doing this or should I be overriding the Draw method of the UIButton and calling SetNeedsDisplay to trigger the redraw?

```
internal class HappyCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private bool _favorite;
    private UIButton _button;

    public bool Favorite {
        get { return _favorite; }
        private set {
            _favorite = value;
            if (_button != null) {
                _button.SetImage (_favorite ? FavImage : FavedImage, UIControlState.Normal);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is how I would do it, overriding `Draw` is usually overkill.  Is something not working for you?

Comment: No it's working but I'm a bit of newb at this and I would like to get the idiomatic usage plus feel confident I'm not giving myself potential performance headaches.

Comment: Overriding cell and making custom setter for data fields is a good way to update cell's state.